In SwiftData I keep getting the error "to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)" and can't solve the problem
I have the following SwiftData models and am trying to write unit tests for them. I can retrieve the data and also filter on non-relationship properties. Unfortunately, this does not work for relationship properties and I always get the error message "error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
<NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600003b3ff00> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
I have been trying to solve the problem for days but unfortunately without success.
I would like to retrieve all classes for which the student "Bob" is entered. Can someone help me and explain what I am doing wrong
@Model
public final class StudentModel {
    
    public var name: String?
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \ClassModel.students)
    public var classes: [ClassModel]?
    
    public init(
        name: String
    ) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
public final class ClassModel {
    
    public var subject: String?
    public var students: [StudentModel]?
    
    public init(
        subject: String,
        students: [StudentModel] = []
    ) {
        self.subject = subject
        self.students = students
    }
}

final class ClassesAndStudents: XCTestCase {
    
    private var modelContainer: ModelContainer? = {
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(
                for: ClassModel.self,
                configurations: modelConfiguration
            )
        }
        catch {
            XCTFail("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }()

    @MainActor
    func testManyToManyFetch() throws {
        let sut = self.modelContainer!.mainContext
        
        let susan = StudentModel(name: "Susan")
        sut.insert(susan)
        let bob = StudentModel(name: "Bob")
        sut.insert(bob)
        let josie = StudentModel(name: "Josie")
        sut.insert(josie)
        
        let mathClass = ClassModel(
            subject: "Math",
            students: [
                susan,
                bob,
                josie
            ]
        )
        sut.insert(mathClass)
        
        let biologyClass = ClassModel(
            subject: "Biology",
            students: [
                susan,
                josie
            ]
        )
        sut.insert(biologyClass)
            
        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<ClassModel>(predicate: #Predicate {
                $0.students.flatMap { $0.contains { $0.name == "Bob" } } ?? false
            })
            let classes = try sut.fetch(descriptor) // ERROR: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600003b46840> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
            XCTAssertEqual(classes.count, 1, "There should be 1 class from fetch")
        }
        catch {
            XCTFail("Fetch failed: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77813560/swiftdata-filtering-on-a-many-to-many-relationship

Unfortunately not. If I try to make the relationship properties non-optional I get the error message on start:
Unresolved error loading container Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=CloudKit integration requires that all relationships be optional, the following are not: ClassModel: students StudentModel: classes}
CloudKit integration requires that all relationships be optional! Many examples on the Internet show these with non-relationship properties.

It would be much easier to fetch students and get the classes that way. let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<StudentModel>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == "Bob" }) and then map to ClassModel, let classes = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor).map(\.classes). Probably more efficient too since there are more students than classes.
